# How can I compare a variable that is passed to a function with a string in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

When I tried to compare a variable with a string, it gives me an error. I tried to compare it with `(= ?a "s")`.

This is the full code example that produces the error:

```
(deffunction cierto (?a)
  (if (= ?a "s")
    then
      (printout t TRUE crlf)
    else
      (printout t FALSE crlf)
  )
)
```

The error:

```
Defining deffunction: cierto
[ARGACCES5] Function = expected argument #2 to be of type integer or float

ERROR:
(deffunction MAIN::cierto
   (?a)
   (if (= ?a "s")
FALSE
```

Comment: Perhaps post the error message?

Comment: error message added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(deffunction cierto (?a)
  (if (eq ?a "s")
    then
      (printout t TRUE crlf)
    else
      (printout t FALSE crlf)
  )
)
```

**(= )** is for comparing numbers (INTEGER or FLOAT) for equality.

- (= 3 3.0) is TRUE
- (= 3 3)  is TRUE
- (= s s) ERROR, s is not a NUMBER

**(eq )** is for comparison of PRIMITIVE values and also comparison of types)

- (eq 6 6.0) is FALSE, different types (INTEGER vs. FLOAT)
- (eq 6 6) is TRUE, same type same value (INTEGER INTEGER)
- (eq si "si") is FALSE, different types (SYMBOL vs. STRING)
- (eq si si) is TRUE, same type, same values (SYMBOL SYMBOL)
- (eq "si" "si") is TRUE, same type same values (STRING STRING)

More information in the Basic Programming Guide (Section 12: Actions And Functions)

Alternative:

```
(deffunction cierto2 (?a)
  (printout t (eq ?a "s") crlf)
)
```

You cold also use a SYMBOL s instead of a STRING "s".